# How to set "N/A" if data is null in angular

Tags: angular

Lets say i have a table and sometimes few data's can be null but null data are showing undefined at the table instead of showing undefine i want to show "N/A" how can i achieve that ill share an image and a code below.

at the above image under reference data some of the data showing undefine because it is null i want it to show "N/A". I'll share the code below. Below code there is "a.normalRange" variable that variable holds the reference data.

```
 var col = ["Test Name", "Result", "Unit" , "Reference"];
    this.xyz.forEach((a) => {
      medicineInfo = this.xyz.find(x => x.id == a.id);
      rows.push(['' + a.xyz+' '+ a.xyz+ '', '' + a.xyz+ '', '' + a.xyz,'' + a.xyz]);
    });
```

And this is how i print the table

```
 doc.autoTable({
            columnStyles: {
              0: { cellWidth: 45 },
              1: { cellWidth: 45 },
              2: { cellWidth: 45 },
              3: { cellWidth: 45 }
            },
            head: [col],
            body: rows,
            startY: 100,
            theme: 'plain',
            tableLineColor: [242, 238, 238],
            tableLineWidth: 0.5,
            styles: {
              font: 'courier',
              lineColor: [242, 238, 238],
              lineWidth: 0.5
            },
          });
```

Comment: can u post ur html code of that row

Comment: i didnt use html for this code i use the jspdf and solve it in typescript(angular)

Comment: It's one of Angular's most frustrating thing: Building tables and manipulate the data for display. 
In my personal experience (or what I've done) I either, build a middle-ware on the back-end so that the API sends the data as expected for display, or, I build a special "table" model. But I'm sure someone might have a more effective solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any other value need to be checked call **isValueEmpty** method with that value.

```js
const col = ["Test Name", "Result", "Unit" , "Reference"];
this.hubxDataItemSpList.forEach((a) => {
    medicineInfo = this.hubxDataItemSpList.find(x => x.id == a.id);
    const normalRange = changeIfValueEmpty(a.normalRange);
    rows.push(['' + a.categoryName +' '+ a.itemTitle + '', '' + a.itemValue + '', '' + a.itemUnit ,'' + normalRange]);
});

function changeIfValueEmpty(value) {
    value = value ?? ''; // reassigned if value is null or undefined
    return (value value.trim() === '') ? 'N/A' : value; // to check value only contains whitespace
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the coalescing operator, which tests for null and undefined.

```
{{ item.value ?? 'N/A' }}
```

If you also want 0 and `''` to be counted as N/A, then use the short circuit :

```
{{ item.value || 'N/A' }}
```

Or, apply this to your TS logic (and also improve it) :

```js
rows.push([
  `${a.categoryName} ${a.itemTitle}`.trim() ?? 'N/A',
  a.itemValue ?? 'N/A',
  a.itemUnit ?? 'N/A',
  a.normalRange ?? 'N/A',
]);
```

(You can apply this to every line if you want)

Comment: since numbers are coming OR (||) operator might show N/A for 0 value too.

Comment: @sasi66 maybe you should pay better attention to what I wrote.

Comment: still showing undefined i have tried both

Comment: @KingCk in that case it means the value of your variable is `'undefined'`, as a string.

Comment: a.normalRange data is a string so how do i fix it

Comment: Please add to your question a sample of your data coming from the API

Comment: i have added the data from api please check

Answer (score 2):

Create angular 'pipe' that returns 'N/A' when value is undefined or null. And use it in html code when needed.

Comment: That one could actually be very elegant.

Comment: Overkill when a simple operator `??` can do the same thing.